# What to all copy into project?

Tags: android

It is recommended that you copy images into your project. But what about everything else?

I designed an app on 2.1... but it looks different on 2.3.3. There are minor things like the background of alert dialogs, context menus, options menus. And for some reason I can't get this ic_dialog_generic to show up in 2.3.3 even though I have it in my project.

What's the best way to handle these things?

Answer (score 1):

This only partially answers your question, but you can sometimes reuse drawables from android.R.drawables. In practice, I've seen my interface stay readable and fashionable enough through android 2.1 to 3.0 using the public drawables in context menus and the like.

See [this useful resource based on stock android 2.2](http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/)